# call application controller method from engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, rails-engines

How do I call a method from ApplicationController in a rails engine?

We are using [ckeditor gem](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) to integrate ckeditor in our rails app. Since we implemented our own authorization system, I need to make a custom ckeditor authorization hook which needs to get the current_user object to decide whether engine controller-action is allowed for this user.

I have current_user defined in mail_app ApplicationController, I want to call it from CKeditor::ApplicationController.

I have included my code here

config/inititializers/ckeditor.rb

```
Ckeditor.setup do |config|
  config.current_user_method  do
    current_user
  end
  config.authorize_with :chronus
end
```

lib/ckeditor/hooks/chronus.rb

```
module Ckeditor
  module Hooks
    class ChronusAuthorization

      include Ckeditor::Helpers::Controllers

      def initialize(controller)
        @controller = controller
        @controller.extend ControllerExtension
      end

     def authorize(action, model_object = nil)
        raise Authorization::PermissionDenied unless authorized?(action, model_object)
      end

      def authorized?(action, model_object = nil)
        if action
          if @controller.current_user_for_chronus.is_admin?
            [:index, :create, :destroy].include? action
          else
            [:create].include? action
          end
        end
      end

      private

      module ControllerExtension
        def current_user_for_chronus
          ckeditor_current_user
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Ckeditor::AUTHORIZATION_ADAPTERS[:chronus] = Ckeditor::Hooks::ChronusAuthorization
```

There is [suggestion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#using-a-controller-provided-by-the-application) in rails guide to make the engine's scoped ApplicationController to inherit from the main ApplicationController. But I cannot do that as engine here is an external gem. (Or is there a way to change the inheriting class?)

Comment: It's generally better to post code here for posterity rather than have it an an external link that will eventually stop working.

Comment: @tadman I have included the code